# Create table with for loop postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

I have a function test_func() that takes in 1 argument (let's say the argument name is X) and returns a table. Now, I have a list of inputs (from a subquery) that I want to pass into argument X and collect all the results of the calls in a table.

In Python, I would do something like

```
# create empty list
all_results = []

for argument in (1,2,3):
    result = test_func(argument)

# Collect the result
all_results.append(result)

return all_results
```

How can I do the same thing in postgresql?

Thank you.

---

For the sake of example, my test_func(X) takes in 1 argument and spits out a table with 3 columns. The values for col1 is  X, col2 is X+1 and col3 is X+3. For example:

```
select * from test_func(1)
```

gives

```
|col1|col2|col3|
----------------
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
----------------
```

My list of arguments would be results of a subquery, for example:

```
select * from (values (1), (2)) x
```

I expect something like:

```
|col1|col2|col3|
----------------
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
----------------
| 2  | 3  | 4  |
----------------
```

Comment: What is the source of your arguments? What do want in the end? An array? A table with one row per result?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. my source of argument is going to be from a subquery.

Comment: the test_func() would returns multiple rows. So for example, each call of test_func() returns 10 rows, and if I have 2 inputs to the argument X, I would get 20 rows. I hope this is clear.

Comment: So the test_func returns a set?

Comment: it returns a table (forgive me if they're the same thing).

Comment: the returning table contains one column?

Comment: no, it returns multiple columns.

Comment: Because you expected output is not quite clear: Is this what you are expecting? The input data from a subquery, the function returns several rows per call and multiple columns, every result is combined into one final result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=08c270e57dd6888118ee124c69a13428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=08c270e57dd6888118ee124c69a13428)

This gives you a result list of all results:

```
SELECT 
    mt.my_data as input,
    tf.*
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM my_table) mt,  -- input data from a subquery
    test_func(my_data) tf         -- calling every data set as argument
```

In the fiddle the `test_func()` gets an `integer` and generates rows (input argument = generated row count). Furthermore, it adds a `text` column. For all inputs all generated records are unioned into one result set.

Comment: You don't need a sub-query there: `... from my_table, test_func(my_data) mf`  will work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I just wanted to demonstrate the subquery point the TO made. He wrote that he was using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your function to the input values:

```
select f.* 
from (
  values (1), (2)
) as x(id) 
   cross join lateral test_func(x.id) as f;
```

Comment: It throws a "syntax error at the end of input" message.

Comment: @QuyVuXuan: ah, sorry. Fixed the typo